# Rails ActiveJob Start From Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I have some custom code that calls some backend systems and updates the database remotely. I have an ActiveJob that performs the task:

```
## Runs join code
class DataJoin < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform
    join = Joiner.new
    join.run
    NotifMailer.sample_email.deliver_now
  end
end
```

I want to kick off an ActiveJob manually from a controller/view:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_action :verify_is_admin

  private def verify_is_admin
      (current_user.nil?) ? redirect_to(root_path) : (redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?)
  end

  def index
    @username = current_user.name
    @intro = "Welcome to the admin console"
  end

  def join
   ## Code to start ActiveJob DataJoin??
  end
end
```

How can I kick off an ActiveJob from a controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
DataJoin.perform_later
```

[`perform_later`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#enqueue-the-job) enqueues the job in the specified queue. If the `perform` method of your active job accepts some arguments, you can even pass them in `perform_later`, and those will be available at the time of execution.

```
DataJoin.perform_later(1, 2, 3)

# DataJoin
def perform(a1, a2, a3)
  # a1 will be 1
  # a2 will be 2
  # a3 will be 3
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [official guide on ActiveJob](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#enqueue-the-job)

```
def join
  DataJoin.perform_later
end
```